# Annotate Singleton objects in JavaScript for the Google Closure Compiler, or "dangerous use of the global this object" warning

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, jsdoc

I'm working with the Google Closure Compiler in ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS compilation level and have started to annotate my constructors because I get all kinds of warnings:

> WARNING - dangerous use of the global this object

For my 'constructor' type functions I'll annotate them like this:

```
/**
 * Foo is my constructor
 * @constructor
 */
Foo = function() {
   this.member = {};
}

/**
 * does something
 * @this {Foo}
 */
Foo.prototype.doSomething = function() {
   ...
}
```

That seems to work fine, however what if I have a 'singleton' object that isn't constructed with var myFoo = new Foo(); 
I couldn't find in the documentation how to annotate this type of object because its type is just object right?

```
Bar = {
   member: null,
   init: function() {
      this.member = {};
   }
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is **exactly** the type of potential bug that "dangerous use of this" warns you against.  In your example, the Closure Compiler **may** try to "flatten" your code to:

```
Bar$member = null;
Bar$init = function() { this.member = {}; };
```

*NOTE: The Closure Compiler currently will not flatten a namespace that is declared as a global object (i.e. without the "var" keyword in front), so your code may still work now.  However, there is no telling that it won't do that in a future version and your code will suddenly break without warning.*

Of course, then "Bar$member" and "Bar$init" will be renamed to "a" and "b" respectively.  This is called "namespace flattening" or "collapsing of properties".

You can **immediately** see that your code no longer works correctly.  Before compilation, if you write:

```
Bar.init();
```

`this` will refer to `Bar`.  However, after compilation it becomes:

```
Bar$init();
```

`this` will no longer refer to `Bar`.  Instead it refers to the global object.

This is way the compiler is trying to warn you that using "this" in such a way is "dangerous", because "this" may be changed to refer to the "global" object.  That's the true meaning of the warning.

In short, **DO NOT DO THIS**.  This type of coding style creates bugs that are *very* difficult to track down.

Modify your code this way:

```
var Bar = {    // Closure Compiler treats globals and properties on global differently
  member: null,
  init: function() { Bar.member = {}; }
};
```

or use a closure:

```
var Bar = (function() {
  var member = null;
  return {
    init: function() { member = {}; }
  };
})();
```

When using the Closure Compiler in Advanced Mode, do not try to get rid of warnings by annotating them away.  Warnings are there for a reason -- they try to warn you about something.

Comment: Thank you, makes sense that referencing the singleton name inside instead of this will prevent the compiler from flattening my singleton.

Comment: Well, @Matt Palmerlee, it is not that.  Referencing the namespace (i.e. singleton) name instead of using "this" avoids an error when the compiler flattens your singleton.  In other words, after compilation, your "singleton" object doesn't exist any more.  However, as I wrote, this only applies if your namespace is prefixed by "var".  Otherwise, your namespace will not be flattened and your program will continue to work, even if you do not eliminate the "dangerous this" warning.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @Stephen Chung, I'm not using the var syntax because my code it a bit more complex than my simple sample, I have a global Application 'namespace' object that the Bar singleton is a member of, so I declare it like: var AppNS = {}; AppNS.Bar = {...};  Either way I went ahead and used the full name AppNS.Bar inside the singleton so that the warning wouldn't appear and it would be more future proof.  Thanks.

Comment: @Matt, great.  Doing one `var AppNS = {};` is enough.  That makes the entire namespace a global property, instead of a global object.  Closure doesn't do any optimizations on global objects.

Answer (score 9):

The preferred way of creating singletons in Closure is like this:

```
/** @constructor */
var Bar = function() { };
goog.addSingletonGetter(Bar);

Bar.prototype.member = null;

Bar.prototype.init = function() {
  this.member = {};
};
```

This allows for lazy instantiation of the singleton. Use it like this:

```
var bar1 = Bar.getInstance();
var bar2 = Bar.getInstance();

bar1.init();
console.log(bar2.member);
```

Keep in mind that this doesn't prevent people from using the constructor to create instances of `Bar`.

Comment: Thanks for that, however I've not been using the Closure Library at all in my js, just the closure compiler to get minified and (somewhat) obfuscated code.  Do I need to go through the library so I can access methods such as addSingletonGetter in order to achieve this?  I like how clean my singleton objects are right now and I'd rather not have to break that just so the compiler advanced mode works for them.